# Dropdown menu not showing up

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

I have been looking at multiple stackoverflow questions about how to get a dropdown menu working, but so far none of them solved the problem. I have a navigation list with a couple of links in it and would like to have a hover option on one of them that would drop down a more specific list of options.

Here is the HTML of the list:

```
    <div id="leftMenu" ng-if="loggedin">
            <li><a href="{{user.oikeudet[100]}}" ng-if="user.oikeudet[100]">Koti</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{user.oikeudet[1000]}}" ng-if="user.oikeudet[1000]">Jäsentiedot</a></li>
            <li>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                            <a href="{{user.oikeudet[10002]}}" ng-if="user.oikeudet[10002]">Asukastiedot</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-content" role="menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Kaste</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="{{user.oikeudet[1001]}}" ng-if="user.oikeudet[1001]">Raportointi</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{user.oikeudet[10001]}}" ng-if="user.oikeudet[10001]">Toiminnot</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{user.oikeudet[10000]}}" ng-if="user.oikeudet[10000]">Admin</a></li>
    </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.dropdown {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: -1px;
}
.dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    width:auto;
    z-index:1000;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block; margin-top: 0;}
```

Thanks in advance for your help on this problem!

Answer (score 0):

```css
        .sub {
            display: none;
        }

        .main > li:hover .sub {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
    <ul class="main">
        <li>a
            <ul class="sub">
                <li>a1</li>
                <li>a2</li>
                <li>a3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>b
            <ul class="sub">
                <li>b1</li>
                <li>b2</li>
                <li>b3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li >c
            <ul class="sub">
                <li>c1</li>
                <li>c2</li>
                <li>c3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```